# why are ICT machines so expensive?

Tags: fpga, analog, test-equipment

For example, take the HP/Agilent/Keysight i3070 ICT machine... why are there so many custom chips on in it? Couldn't the same thing be done with off the shelf FPGAs/opamps and relays? The tests it runs aren't *that* sophisticated. Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: At some bandwidths, FPGAs become infeasible. Also, yes, calibrating something to reliably give sub-0.1dB resolution is much more expensive than you seem to think. Same goes for exact frequency and power sources.

Answer (score 2):

They ARE made of FPGAs, opamps, relays, spring loaded contacts, automated robotic loading, usually combine at least six different instruments to perform the job. Have you any chance to examine many videos available before asking this question? This [one to start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixUJRRBt4YQ), or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw6RYvyVdFk).

Plus the entire production volume of these machines may be less than thousand units, that's why they cost a lot. If you believe this is simple, you can start your own business and compete with Keysight, and a bunch of European ([watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjmjYVNuLEE)), Japanese, Chinese, and other companies.